# even and odd cubic polynomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus, approximation-theory

Book says approximating even function  $P_3$ must be of form $ax^2+b\ $so they neglected $x,x^3\ $. This function approximate even function $|x|^3$
very nicely in the book after some tweaking.

I am thinking if I was to approximate an odd fuction with polynomial of degree 3 should I ditch term $x^2\ $  and have it as $ax^3 + bx + c\ $
When I draw this function it make sense.
Here is the graph of modified polynomial and 2 odd functions $x^3\ $ and $sin x$.
[image]

Comment: With the constant $c=0$ your degree-three function is odd, otherwise it is not.  What is your question exactly?

Comment: You wouldn’t even had $c$ for odd functions.

Comment: Don't forget that zero is an even number and that the constant term can be thought of as the "$x^0$ term."  Remember also your definition for an even function and an odd function.  An even function is one such that $f(x)=f(-x)$ while an odd function is one such that $f(x)=-f(-x)$.

Comment: I don't understand how a constant can change function from odd to even ?

Comment: oh I see.  thank you.

Comment: Rephrased in more layman terms., an even function has reflective symmetry across the $y$ axis.  An odd function has rotational symmetry of $180^\circ$ around the origin.  By adding a constant to an odd function, it would still have rotational symmetry but not around the origin anymore.  Note also that every odd function must satisfy that $f(0)=0$ since $f(0)=-f(-0)$.